# Cheese not working in HP Laptop

Tags: webcam

After installing ubuntu latest version the webcam of my HP laptop doesn't work. I have installed cheese but the window of cheese is black it doesn't show anything.

[image]

I checked on google but there is no possible solution that could solve this problem.

The light on my webcam turns on but the cheese doesn't show anything.

Comment: Please be specific on your release; latest released was 16.04.7, before that 18.04.5, a week earlier 20.04.1 was released; so please be specific. It's best if we're not making assumptions.

Comment: 20.04.1 is the version of ubuntu I just installed

Comment: I am looking for ways to reinstall drivers but it always get to cheese but cheese is not working

Comment: Do you have any idea @guiverc

Comment: Check if camera is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Are you a member of the `video` group? `id` will show. `sudo adduser $USER video`, then logout an login. Look at `ls -l /dev/video*`.